# Git, Committing unnatural commits

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

Due to changing product needs, I need to do something that seems unnatural.  Long story short I need to base a commit off an old commit, commit the changes into the main branch, then get what was previously the main branch and put that on top of that commit.  What should have been a 5-minute job has taken over an hour due to the user hostility of Git and SourceTree and has resulted in what appears to be 5 branches.

I'll try to graph out what I'm trying to do below so it makes more sense.  Probably easiest to read it bottom to top:

```
[]              <- New master which is Commit A minus an old file
[] ---\         <- Branch B is merged
[] \  []        <- Branch A is merged
[] [] []        <- Branch A is based off another, way older branch, code just cut and paste in.  Branch B is the same as Commit A minus an old file
[] /--/         <- Commit A gets two branches
```

I'm pretty much losing my mind here, not sure what to search for and not sure how to do this since apparently, I can't just branch off twice and re-commit.  When I try to merge Branch B in master from the example above it either doesn't do anything or it, according to SourceTree, only changes one thing and disregards all of the other changes in Branch B (essentially making master the same as Branch A which is what I'm trying to avoid).  I tried rebasing master, however, after doing that and committing, it threw Branch A off the main line, which is not what I'm looking to do at all.  At this point, I have 4 branches merged and/or floating in space with a master branch that shoots past it all.  I don't care about it looking clean, I just need to have this merge properly.

Thank you

Comment: Suggestion: don't think about *branches*. Think only about *commits*. What sequence of commits do you want to have? What should each commit's parent(s) be, and what should its corresponding source tree be? Draw those out (on whiteboard, paper, whatever). Only once you have all of those figured out should you concern yourself with branch *names*. This is because that is also how Git works, so you will be well set up at that point to make Git accomplish what you want. (Also, I think you are halfway to this point already!)

Comment: Sounds like a 5 minute job with `git rebase -i`

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure it's not the right way of doing things, but -torek set me on the right track; think about commits not branches.  So, I just cut and paste all the files in two different commits.  Now everything is in order, except for the branches to nowhere but whatever, they can rot.

Thanks.